# CIFilter output image nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

I am using core image and I am applying a CIFilter sepia tone to my image. I run a filter once in viewDidLoad and then immediately call another function that adds the filter again. For some reason, when I try to access the output image, the app crashes and says the output image is nil. Anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myimage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let image = CIImage(image: myimage.image)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
        filter.setDefaults()
        filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        myimage.image = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)
        self.reapplyFilter()
    }

        func reapplyFilter(){
            let image = CIImage(image: myimage.image)
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
            filter.setDefaults()
            filter.setVa    lue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    //ERROR HERE: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            myimage.image = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)
//ERROR
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }



}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot call `UIImage(CIImage:)` and use that UIImage as the image of a UIImageView. UIImageView requires a UIImage backed by a bitmap (CGImage). A UIImage instantiated with CIImage has no bitmap; it has no actual image, it's just a set of instructions for applying a filter. That is why your UIImageView's image is nil.

Comment: And see my book on how to extract a _real_ image from a CIImage: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_cifilter_and_ciimage

Comment: And for Swift code: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch02p070filters/ch15p419filters/ViewController.swift

Comment: I find that the solution outlined by http://stackoverflow.com/users/1955870/fz does work (using `CIContext`). Is there an associated risk?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect That answer is what I am saying _to_ do. That is totally different from calling `UIImage(CIImage:)` and sticking that in an image view; that is what I am saying _not_ to do. - And see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_cifilter_and_ciimage

Comment: @SwiftArchitect linked to a user. More usefully, here is the [link to the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28386693/199364) he refers to. This shows the correct way to code this.

Answer (score 9):

A couple of things here:

1) Using the CIImage constructor to create a CIImage based on a non CIImage backed UIImage is dangerous and will return nil or an empty CIImage.

2) When creating the image back I'd suggest you to use CIContext instead of UIImage(CIImage:).

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myimage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myimage.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        self.applyFilter()
        self.applyFilter()
    }

    func applyFilter(){
        let image = CIImage(CGImage: myimage.image?.CGImage)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
        filter.setDefaults()
        filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let imageRef = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage, fromRect: image.extent())
        myimage.image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Made is an `IBInspectable UIImageView` and posted the code on https://gist.github.com/SwiftArchitect/676007e8e1c77e632520