# Why do I need UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext to get proper UIImage rendered from CIImage

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, ciimage

Can someone explain to me why this displays the image improperly:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "test-pattern.jpg")
let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)
myUIImageView.image = UIImage(CIImage: ciImage)
```

but this doesn't:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "test-pattern.jpg")
var ciImage = CIImage(image: image)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(ciImage.extent().size.height,ciImage.extent().size.width))

var testUIImage = UIImage(CIImage: ciImage)

testUIImage?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, ciImage.extent().size.height, ciImage.extent().size.width))

let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

var image = UIImage(named: "test-pattern.jpg")
let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)
```

Is this the way it's supposed to be done, or can this be accomplished more efficiently?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I don't think `UIImageView` is able to display images that are backed by a `CIImage`

Comment: See also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28386697/341994

Comment: Ok, I can see why this example makes no sense.. why go from UIImage -> CIImage -> back to UIImage? What I'm trying to do is sort out some rendering issues I'm having after taking a UIImage, running it through a CIFilter and rendering it back to the screen. I think my issue is in the CIImage -> UIImage  step so I'm trying to sort out how that works to isolate my problem.

Comment: You need to create a `CIContext` and use the `createCGImage:fromRect:` to get a `CGImage` from your `CIImage` and then create a `UIImage` out of that.

Comment: It's confusing to me that UIImage class has init(CIImage:) initializer. Apple's documentation implies to me that this creates a UIImage object using a CIImage instance ?