# UIImagePNGRepresentation always nil for generated QR image

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to save a QR code image that was generated in my app, and when doing so I am unable to get the underlying data so that I can save it.

The QR code is generated via `CIFilter`s from a string, nothing special, like so:

```
 if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {

        //set the data to the contact data
        filter.setValue(contactData, forKey: "inputMessage")
        filter.setValue("L", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

        if let qrImage = filter.outputImage {
            self.qrCode = UIImage(ciImage: codeImage)
        }
    }
}
```

And, I'm trying to get the image data to save it to the application documents by doing so:

`let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.qrCode)`

But, it always returns `nil`.

I understand the documentation saying that it can return nil if no underlying data is found,

*but* I am confused at how I can store this image that is generated if there is no underlying data?

Comment: where are you calling the UIImagePNGRepresentation function?

Comment: Take a look at this thtead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386344/cifilter-output-image-nil?rq=1

Comment: @ChristianAbella I am calling it inside of a class that creates the image

Comment: can you show your other code?

Comment: @ChristianAbella What specifically? The class is just a normal swift class that is initialized by passing as string, the QR image is generated just by running the code above, and outputted just from a function call, what else would you like to see ?

Comment: because this is an async call filter.outputImage, and it is likely that when you call it to save it has not yet finish processing.

Comment: @ChristianAbella I see, how can I get around that?